# Jasper Reports in Scala using dynamic list of objects as data source

Tags: scala, jasper-reports

I'm attempting to write a Jasper Report program in Scala, where the data structure is created dynamically. The data source would be a list of `Data` objects (see case class below), where each Data object is a list of Strings and Ints.

Each line in the report will have fields such as Data.strings(0), Data.strings(1) and so on.

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine._
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data._

case class Data (strings: Array[String], ints: Array[Int] )

val str1 = Array("String11", "String12")
val int1 = Array(11,12)
val str2 = Array("String21", "String22")
val int2 = Array(21,22)

val data1 = Data(str1, int1)
val data2 = Data(str2, int2)

val dataSource = new JRBeanArrayDataSource(Array(data1, data2));      

val params = new HashMap[String,String](Map("1"->"one", "2"->"two"))

val jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("test1.jasper", params, dataSource);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "test1.pdf");
```

Problem is that the `JasperFillManager.fillReport` line doesn't compile with the following error, aparently because the list of Data objects is not supported:

> ◾overloaded method value fillReport with alternatives: (x$1:
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport,x$2:
>   java.util.Map[String,Object],x$3:
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource)net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint
>    (x$1: java.io.InputStream,x$2: java.util.Map[String,Object],x$3:
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource)net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint
>    (x$1: String,x$2: java.util.Map[String,Object],x$3:
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource)net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint
>    (x$1: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport,x$2:
>   java.util.Map[String,Object],x$3:
>   java.sql.Connection)net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint 
>   (x$1: java.io.InputStream,x$2: java.util.Map[String,Object],x$3:
>   java.sql.Connection)net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint 
>   (x$1: String,x$2: java.util.Map[String,Object],x$3:
>   java.sql.Connection)net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint cannot be
>   applied to (String, java.util.HashMap[Int,String],
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanArrayDataSource)

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: Can you show your imports, maybe you are not using java.util.HashMap?

Comment: added the imports, I'm using `java.util.HashMap`. Also, changed params to `HashMap[String,String]` and still same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem: declaring the HashMap as [String,Object] explicitly:

```
val params = new HashMap[String,Object](Map("1"->"one", "2"->"two"))
```